# how to combine strings in a list that have same length and create lists of list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings. Based on the length of each string, I need to group them in one list. finally one list should contain all the lists.

Example:

input

```
in=['the', 'way', 'you', 'see', 'people', 'is', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'treat', 'them', 'and', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'treat', 'them', 'is', 'what', 'they', 'become']
```

output

```
expected_out=[['is'],['and', 'see', 'the', 'way', 'you'], ['them', 'they', 'what'], ['treat'], ['become', 'people']]
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Off the top of my head: make a loop that increments a counter (initialize it to the minimum word length). For every loop, check the length of the words. If len(word) == counter_value, add the word to a temporary list and remove it so it's not inspected again the next time. After the loop, add the temporary list to a "master" list (2D list), clear the temporary list, increment the counter and start over. Might be a stupid way to do it - I don't know. It works in my head :P

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it's the first thing that came to my mind:

```
from collections import defaultdict

len2words = defaultdict(set)

for word in input_list:
    len2words[len(word)].add(word)

output = [list(len2words[key]) for key in sorted(len2words.keys())]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `itertools.groupby` as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['the', 'way', 'you', 'see', 'people', 'is', 'the', 'way',
      'you', 'treat', 'them', 'and', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'treat',
      'them', 'is', 'what', 'they', 'become']

l.sort(key=len)
output = [list(set(items)) for length, items in groupby(l, key=len)]
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[['is'], ['and', 'the', 'see', 'you', 'way'], ['them', 'what', 'they'], 
 ['treat'], ['become', 'people']]
```

This sorts the strings by length before grouping consecutive strings with the same length. A list comprehension is then used to unpack unique strings into sublists through the use of `set`.

Comment: Thanks a million!! this helped me to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) combined with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) so as to not modify the ordering of your original input data.

```
data = ['the', 'way', 'you', 'see', 'people', 'is', 'the', 'way',
     'you', 'treat', 'them', 'and', 'the', 'way', 'you', 'treat', 
     'them', 'is', 'what', 'they', 'become']

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=len)
result = [list(set(group[1])) for group in groupby(sorted_data, key=len)]

'''
[['is'], 
 ['and', 'the', 'see', 'you', 'way'], 
 ['them', 'what', 'they'], 
 ['treat'], 
 ['become', 'people']]
'''
```

Comment: I would split that up a little.  As it is, it is very hard to read.